# How To Get Latest Comments First? [Like Facebook Comment System]

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-comments

I am trying to display the latest comments in the database I have tried DESC this displays comments from top to below which is alright but not what I need I also tried ASC and that's not displaying the most recent comments as I have a LIMIT.

I need it to work exactly how the facebook comment system works.

Here's the code

```
$select_comments2 = $db->query("
SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_comments WHERE post_id='$escape_post_id_row' AND post_id='$_GET[pid]' ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: *I can't be bothered* - then why should we bother? Don't make your problem our problem.  It's hard enough to troubleshoot - give us the minimal code required to create the problem.

Comment: `Yes i know its loong but you will earn great reputation if you can help` If you can't be bothered to reduce the code you've posted to the relevant section, then why should we be bothered to post any answer regardless of the promise of earning great reputation? Make the effort to narrow the code down (even if just to yoru SQL queries)

Comment: Ok fine I see your point I am just frustrated as I worked all day to try and solve this and nothing seems to work I posted the query as that's all you would need
hope this helps more

I need the latest comment to display from bottom to top like the facebook comment feature
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you didn't adda timestamp column in your database.

As per the above one, it dont know the time yopu added data. Depending on just the ID will not solve it.

Please add one more column in your database for the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. and sort it like

```
$select_comments2 = $db->query("
SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_comments WHERE post_id='$escape_post_id_row' AND post_id='$_GET[pid]' ORDER BY comment_time DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Ok thanks ;) 
There must be some problem when sorting with the ID then i'm adding A timestamp now let you know if it works

Comment: I appreciate your help ;)
This didn't work I am basically trying the get the latest 10 comments in the database in display bottom to top ordering from post_id DESC did that except that displayed comments from top to bottom
once again hope we can solve this and thanks so far

Bascially how the facebook comment feature works in displaying comments

Comment: U can get the latest by time with this. If you need something other to sort, then you have to add it in database and then check.

Comment: that's what I am trying to do it's actually getting a bit technical for me lol.. I just use DESC and when I get more developers improve this as will as FB got load of developers so there know what there doing hope users don't complain though
thanks ;)

Comment: would it matter if I used desc not sure what else to do and I appreciate your help
Stressed right now :(